# Is it possible to use an S-box similar to the one used in DES in AES? How would this work?

Tags: aes, des, s-boxes

I'm reviewing some questions given to me by a professor and am stumped on this one. My initial guess is that yes, this is possible, but I do not know how to explain it, specifically for a function $\{0,1\}^8\to \{0,1\}^6$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

DES is a [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) that doesn't require the $F$ function to be reversible, where the S-Boxes are used. DES has a non-reversible $F$ function in which the 8 S-boxes $S:\{0,1\}^6\to \{0,1\}^4$ is used.

AES is based on [Susbstition Permutation Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution%E2%80%93permutation_network) (SPN) where everything must be reversible. AES is using [S-boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) $S:\{0,1\}^8\to \{0,1\}^8$. Therefore it is not possible to use the DES Sboxes in the AES.

Besides the functionality, even if we could interchange them, that would require to analyze, too.